# Visualization of the disintegration theorem

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, soft-question, geometric-measure-theory

Where can I find a picture that gives a visualization of the [disintegration theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem)?

If such reference does not exist, what would a nice visualization of this fundamental result look like?

Comment: Wikipedia article you refer to gives a simple example with Lebesgue measure on the unit square. What other visualization is needed?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Sorry, I was unclear: I meant if there exists a picture to illustrate that example drawn in some book.

Comment: Picture of the unit square partitioned into horizontal segments? Can't you make this picture yourself?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Of course I can do it in a very basic way, I was hoping that there is a more "artistic" version in some measure theory book.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any "visualization" of the disintegration theorem other than the classical Fubini setup (with the unit square projected on the horizontal unit interval). The point (alas, missing in most measure theory courses) is that not only all purely non-atomic Lebesgue spaces (aka standard probability spaces; all Polish topological spaces endowed with a Borel probability measure are in this class) are isomorphic to the unit interval endowed with the Lebesgue measure, but also that any measure preserving map from one Lebesgue space onto another Lebesgue space with purely non-atomic conditional measures is isomorphic to the Fubini map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I was a bit unclear: I meant to ask if in some book there exists a picture to illustrate the simple example you mentioned.

Comment: BTW. could you please give a reference to th result wchich you have mentioned (about uniqueness of the Fubini map)? I would be grateful

Comment: For instance, see Section 2.3 (in particular, Corollary 1) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.06619.pdf.

Comment: @RW Actually, figure 1 of that paper may be exactly what I was looking for.